# STL Container with iterator and inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, object-slicing

Here is a sample C++ question to find out the outcome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    A(int n = 0) : m_n(n) { }

public:
    virtual int f() const { return m_n; }
    virtual ~A() { }

protected:
    int m_n;
};

class B
    : public A
{
public:
    B(int n = 0) : A(n) { }

public:
    virtual int f() const { return m_n + 1; }
};

int main()
{
    const A a(1);
    const B b(3);
    const A *x[2] = { &a, &b };
    typedef std::vector<A> V;
    V y({ a, b });
    V::const_iterator i = y.begin();

    std::cout << x[0]->f() << x[1]->f()
              << i->f() << (i + 1)->f() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output I expected was "1 4 1 4" but the correct answer is "1 4 1 3".

From above,

```
x[0]->f()
```

i.e., x[0] is nothing but a pointer to an object of type A and calling f() returns 1.

```
x[1]->f()
```

i.e., x[1] is nothing but a pointer to an object of type A (base class pointer pointing to derived class object) and calls derived class f() that returns (3 + 1) = 4

I am not sure how this behaves when we add the objects a and b into a vector container and iterating them through const_iterator with inheritance

```
i->f()
```

I can understand this as i is just a pointer to the first element i.e., object a.

But what will happen here?

```
(i + 1)->f()
```

My understanding is that it points to the next element in the sequence i.e., object b and calling f() through derived class pointer should call its member function rather than base class one's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vector `y` contains two objects of type `A`.  Not type `B`.  When it is constructed, it makes copies of `a` and `b`, [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/274634/459640) `b` as it does so.  So `(i + 1)->f()` calls `A::f()` on that copy of the `A` portion of `b`, giving 3.

Comment: So what you want instead is a container of pointers (`std::vector<A*>`) or (better) a container of smart pointers (such as `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>`).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about slicing. I also edited my understanding of x[1]. Can you please correct me if that doesnt make sense?